# Jax traces a static Argument

Tags: python, jax, triton

I am trying to use some Jax code in a Pallas kernel but for some reason my code does not work anymore.

```
import functools
import jax
from jax.experimental import pallas as pl
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np
from jaxtyping import Array
from jax.experimental import sparse

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(52)
other = jax.random.normal(key, (10, 10))
diags = jax.random.normal(key, (3, 10))
offsets = (-2, 1, 2)

def dia_matmul_kernel(diags_ref, offsets, other_ref, o_ref):
    diags, other = diags_ref[...], other_ref[...]
    N = other.shape[0]
    out = jnp.zeros((N, N))
    print(offsets)
    for offset, diag in zip(offsets, diags):
        start = jax.lax.max(0, offset)
        end = min(N, N + offset)
        top = max(0, -offset)
        bottom = top + end - start
        out = out.at[top:bottom, :].add(
            diag[start:end, None] * other[start:end, :]
        )
    o_ref[...] = out

@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1, ))
def dia_matmul(diags: Array, offsets: tuple[int],other:Array) -> Array:    
    return pl.pallas_call(
        dia_matmul_kernel,
        out_shape=jax.ShapeDtypeStruct(other.shape, other.dtype)
    )(diags, offsets ,other)
dia_matmul(diags, offsets,other)
```

I understand that is not best practice to print stuff in a Jax JIT function but when I print my `offsets`, which should be kept static from the `static_argnums=(1,)`, it says:

```
(Traced<MemRef<None>{int32[]}>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=3/0)>, Traced<MemRef<None>{int32[]}>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=3/0)>, Traced<MemRef<None>{int32[]}>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=3/0)>)
```

I don't understand why that is the case, I'm new to Jax and Pallas so I'm not yet fully confident with this whole Tracing concept. Also the last operation of the for loop with the `out` is not working so if anyone also has an idea :D

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The arguments passed to `pallas_call` will always be traced, regardless of whether or not they are static before being passed to `pallas_call`. This is true any time you pass arguments to a JAX primitive, or a transformed function: all inputs will be traced unless explicitly marked as static in the function you are calling.

`pallas_call` doesn't currently have any way of marking static arguments, and will trace all arguments passed to the wrapped function. If you want some arguments to be static, you should be able to do this by closing over them in the function that you pass to `pallas_call`:

```py
@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1, ))
def dia_matmul(diags: Array, offsets: tuple[int],other:Array) -> Array:
    return pl.pallas_call(
        lambda diags, other, o_ref: dia_matmul_kernel(diags, offsets, other, o_ref),
        out_shape=jax.ShapeDtypeStruct(other.shape, other.dtype)
    )(diags, other)
```

Comment: This does not work not it says for the line `start = max(0, offset)` that `AttributeError: 'AbstractMemoryRef' object has no attribute '_gt'`

Comment: It looks like I forgot `o_ref` in the `lambda`: `lambda diags, other, o_ref: dia_matmul_kernel(diags, offsets, other, o_ref),` It looks like there are other issues further along in your code, but that should get you past the dynamic argument issue that is the subject of your original question.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, now I have a problem of slicing an array but it actually says that the primitive in Pallas GPU lowering is not implemented. But anyway I think I am starting to see the light!

Comment: I just saw that you are a contributor on the repo, is there some information somewhere on how this reading and writing into the Refs work? I'm pretty sure my only problem at the moment is `o_ref[...] = out` I think I am using this "eclipse" (??) thingy wrong.

Comment: `NotImplementedError: Unimplemented primitive in Pallas GPU lowering: slice. Please file an issue on https://github.com/google/jax/issues.` Strange since I am not using `jax.lax.slice()`?

Comment: `diag[start:end, None]` is `slice` when `start` and `end` are static.

Comment: I understand but is there a way I can overcome this challenge? I'm not sure if `dynamic_slice` is appropriate here.

Comment: Comment threads on answered StackOverflow questions are not a great forum to get answers to additional questions, particularly if those answers are nontrivial (e.g. it's not possible to write multi-line code blocks here). I'd suggest creating another StackOverflow post, or perhaps asking at https://github.com/google/jax/discussions if your question is more open-ended.

Comment: I managed, to solve my issue meanwhile, but have stumbled upon a matrix multiplication issue when using complex numbers I'll create another post. Thank you for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78102064/complex-vector-multiplication-pallas-jax